# import of keras and tensorflow seems to break pycharm

Tags: keras, pycharm

I'm facing a weird issue.

I'm working in Pycharm IDE and I want to use keras with tensorflow backend.
When I try to import keras or tensorflow pycharm process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

For example

```
import tensorflow as tf 
n_input = 2
print (n_input)
```

returns message described above without printing anything.
If i comment the tf import it works.

`Keras` and `tensorflow` are correctly installed under the python interpreter of my choice.

I'm on windows machine, Python 3.6.8

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this code in an other environnement than pycharm, like the console or a jupyter notebook to see if it's working or not ?

Comment: Ok i can close. It seems that version of keras and version of tensorflow libraries weren't aligned.